# Group duplicated names listed in CSV file and display the total number of each group in seperate Div using d3.js

Tags: csv, d3.js

I have a CSV file with a column containing duplicated names (strings).  I like to group all the aliked/duplicate names, count them/add them and place their total in a div; ie., Div Base 1: 20, Div Base 2: 80,  Div Base 3: 120.  I trying to accomplish this idea using d3.js and I got the names to appear in the div but can't figure out how to create and place the total Base count of the different duplicate names (strings) in the mentioned divs.  Is this possible using D3?  Below is my attempt so far.
CSV column/data look like below:

[image: Sample CSV data]

```
d3.selectAll(".container").append("div")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return  "base" + d.id})
    .html(function(d, i) {  
        if('Base' + d.id === 'Base' + d.id){
                 return data[i].location;
        }
    })
```

```
/////////My modification of your suggestion////////
var baseCount = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.value; })
  .rollup(function(v) { return v.length; })
  .entries(data);
console.log(baseCount); 

// append divs
var mainDiv = d3.selectAll(".imgContainer");

mainDiv.selectAll(".imgContainer").data(baseCount).enter().append("div").attr("id", function(d) { return  "bases" + d.id}).html(function (d) {
  return d.values;
 // return "<pre>" + d[0] + " : " + d[1] + "</pre>";
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 v6 onwards has an [`.rollups`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/main/README.md#rollups) array transformation which suits your need. If you use an earlier version of D3 there is some equivalent, or you can write plain Javascript as well.

The `rollups` method can create a 'summary' of base ids and their count. Then you can pass the output array from this to a data join to create the divs.

Example below:

```js
// summary of data
const baseSummary = d3.rollups(fakeData, v => v.length, d => d.name);

// append divs
const mainDiv = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("id", "main");
  
mainDiv.selectAll(".baseDiv")
  .data(baseSummary)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "baseDiv")
  .html(d => `<pre>${d[0]} : ${d[1]}</pre>`)
```

```css
.baseDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.6.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
const fakeData = [
  {name: 'base3', value: 3},
  {name: 'base1', value: 3},
  {name: 'base1', value: 2},
  {name: 'base3', value: 10},
  {name: 'base2', value: 10},
  {name: 'base2', value: 10},
  {name: 'base1', value: 2},
  {name: 'base1', value: 9},
  {name: 'base1', value: 3},
  {name: 'base2', value: 7},
  {name: 'base2', value: 10},
  {name: 'base2', value: 6},
  {name: 'base1', value: 6},
  {name: 'base3', value: 10},
  {name: 'base1', value: 1},
  {name: 'base3', value: 1},
  {name: 'base3', value: 2},
  {name: 'base3', value: 10},
  {name: 'base2', value: 10},
  {name: 'base2', value: 6},
  {name: 'base3', value: 2},
  {name: 'base2', value: 2},
  {name: 'base1', value: 10},
  {name: 'base2', value: 5},
  {name: 'base2', value: 9},
  {name: 'base2', value: 7},
  {name: 'base2', value: 3},
  {name: 'base1', value: 4},
  {name: 'base1', value: 5},
  {name: 'base3', value: 7}
];
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Robin for the example.  I appreciate it.  Currently my project was created using D3 version 3.  I,m planning to revamp my old script to new, V7.  I haven't done so due to the saying, if it's not broke don't fix it :)  However do you know the lower version equivalent to the D3.rollups(), for version 3? Or a plain javascript method that will work with my current data being loaded with D3 CSV.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Adding to my top comment.  I'm toying with a data.forEach(){ loop and I am able to see via console.log, but I'm unable to add the like names and place it in a global variable to use in my D3 .html() function.  I'm close but yet so far :)

Comment: I was able to get the equivalent to the D3.rollups to work.  But this list of all totals are repeating in the div and not separated in different divs like your example; return "<pre>" + d[0] + " : " + d[1] + "</pre>"; this return data undefined.  But when I return:  d.names it displays what I explained above.  I edited my original post to show my modification to the script you provided.  I'm not seeing why mine is loading the data different.

Comment: Your solution is work perfect!  I corrected a few issues in my tweaks I made in your suggestion and now it's working as expected.  I appreciate the help and education.